# using WDT to monitor if my python program crashes

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, watchdog

**Background**

I'm struggling to find a example of WDT in the way I want to use it.  Wondering if I misunderstanding its use.

my python writing is pure hobby, honestly Classes intimidate me.

in short my program reads a number of sensors connected to a raspberry pi and writes the data to a cloud hosted object database.

i have an intermittent error that while I try to figure out I want to implement a based watchdog timer.

This is what I'd like to implement so in the very least I continue to collect and store data.

I've read about the builtin watchdog timer the raspberry pi has built in here: https://diode.io/raspberry%20pi/running-forever-with-the-raspberry-pi-hardware-watchdog-20202/

The problem I want the raspberry pi to reboot if my program hangs, but when that happens the OS is still fine, so the solution in the link above is not effective.

**What I'd like to implement**:

1. set the builtin watchdog timer to reboot the raspberry pi after 200 seconds without restarting (patting?) the timer.  I think the instructions for this are in the link above.
2. Within my python script, after I iterate through each sensor, restart (or pat?) the watchdog timer and if 200 seconds elapse between pattings (meaning my program hangs) then RPi reboots.

is this possible?

can someone help me with some simple code?  I was hoping to keep this simple and avoid classes and/or threads...

thank you in advance

Comment: You probably dont really want to use the WDT for something like this. Are you running a linux-based OS on the RPi? If you are, you can have the OS manage the starting & restarting of the process.

Comment: @Z4-tier yes:
PRETTY_NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)"
NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="10"
VERSION="10 (buster)"
VERSION_CODENAME=buster
ID=raspbian
ID_LIKE=debian
HOME_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianForums"
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianBugs"

this is the shell script that launches my program: 

xterm -T "HMS" -geometry 100x70+10+35 -hold -e sudo /usr/bin/python3 /home/pi/h$

Answer (score 0):

The WDT is probably not the right solution for the problem you are describing. Based on your description, it sounds like what you have is a program that is intended to run periodically (either on a fixed schedule or in response to some event), and that program currently has a bug that is causing it to hang intermittently and never complete it's task or terminate.

The first and best way to solve that, I'm sure you can guess, is to fix the bug. But your thinking is not unreasonable either, and doing what you describe is very common. There are many valid approaches that will do what you want without the complexity of trying to deal with a hardware timer. One of the easiest is probably to just wrap the program in a shell script and use the `timeout` command to limit how long it is allowed to execute before it is terminated.

Assuming the script is located at `/home/user/my_script.py`, and you want to run it every 10 minutes, allowing it 2 minutes before it is killed, this would work:

1. create a wrapper shell script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

if ! timeout 120s python /home/user/my_script.py; then
  msg="$(date) - script exceeded timeout and was killed"
else
  msg="$(date) - script ran successfully"
fi
echo "${msg}" >> /home/user/my_script.log
```

put the script in a file, say at `/home/user/wrapper_script.sh` and run `chmod 755 /home/user/wrapper_script.sh` to make it executable.

2. schedule the script to run every 10 minutes using cron. At a shell, use `crontab -e` to edit the users crontab file and add a new line like this:

```
*/10 * * * *    /home/user/wrapper_script.sh
```

now, every 10 minutes the wrapper will start automatically, and it will kick off the python script. It will wait 2 minutes for the script to stop normally, after which it will reach the timeout and terminate it.

Note: depending on how your python program is written, you might have to use some other options to the `timeout` command to specify which signal it should use to stop the program. If it is a very basic python script, it should be fine using the default.

Edit: based on the comments, you might be able to just change the command you're using to this:

```
xterm -T "HMS" -geometry 100x70+10+35 -hold -e sudo timeout 120s /usr/bin/python3 /home/pi/h$
```

Doing that won't actually schedule the script to run at any fixed interval, so it assumes you already have something in place to handle that. All this will do is make srue that the script is restricted to 120 seconds of run time before it is killed.

Comment: thank you the clear and detailed response, it is very much appreciated!  Cron jobs was something on my list to learn and now I have a reason.  Thank you again.